# Searching against a large list of people at the same time in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, full-text-search

I have a list of people that varies between `2-5k` entries that has this general format:

`firstname1 lastname1, firstname2 lastname2, firstname3 lastname3 ...`

I have a `user_table` which contains about `250-300k` entries with a `firstname` and `lastname` column.  What I'm trying to do is let users input that list of names into a field, and return all users in the database with matching names.  My first instinct was to create a view called `name_search` that looks like this ->

```
create view name_search as (
  select
    id,
    to_tsvector(concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)) as search_field
  from user_table
)
```

Then I can search against it by turning all the names in the comma separated list into a string like this

`const queryString = "(firstname1 <-> lastname1) | (firstname2 <-> lastname2) | (firstname3 <-> lastname3) ..."`

then I can pass that string into this query

```
select
  *
from name_search 
where search_field @@ to_tsquery(queryString)
```

I'm leaving out some of the details like escaping the string etc etc. but my issue is that this is horribly slow.  I was wondering if someone could help me create a solution to this that is faster.

Comment: You say you have the list,  but then you also say you want to let uses input it.  Those seem like different things.  And input it where?  Into a <textarea></> ? into a database table?

Comment: Sounds like you want to put them into an array and just joining it. Eg `where search_field in (@arr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a case for full text search here.
You can provide your input string as is to this query:

```
SELECT t.id, firstname, lastname
FROM   user_table t
JOIN  (
   SELECT split_part(fullname, ' ', 1) AS firstname
        , split_part(fullname, ' ', 2) AS lastname
   FROM   unnest(string_to_array('firstname1 lastname1, firstname2 lastname2, firstname3 lastname3', ', ')) fullname
   ) input USING (firstname, lastname);
```

An index on `(firstname, lastname)` should help performance while the input list isn't too long. For retrieving more than a couple percent of all rows, a sequential scan is faster anyway.

Related:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612456/939860)
- [PostgreSQL importing thousands of columns as an array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166867/postgresql-importing-thousands-of-columns-as-an-array/166905#166905)
- [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key/46477#46477)